# Do barrier buffs disappear if the enemy casts the same one?

Tags: naruto-online

Lets say for instance I have Gaara and he casts Sand Hell which increases power to my team that lasts for 3 turns. If the enemy Gaara casts Sand Hell as well, I would suspect that my increase in power would go away, but there is no indication that that happens. There is also no indication that the buff only lasts while Sand Hell is still active.

How do the buffs work when another buff or even the same one is cast after mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 1 barrier can exist at the same time, and these buffs are universal unless otherwise stated. In the case of my original question, the buffs to my team will disappear, since Gaara's Sand Hell only affects units on your side of the field.